# Conditionally Chain Single and Completable

Tags: android, multithreading, parallel-processing, kotlin, rx-java

My overall workflow for the Rx calls should work as follows (regardless of the current Rx code):

- Get a list of motion sensor readings from a `Room` `Dao` (with the purpose of uploading them to a REST API). I'm using a `Single<List<Reading>>` for this
- If that `readings` list is empty, then perform a `jobFinished()` callback and *execute nothing after this*
- If `readings` is not empty, then chain a network call to this `Single`. The network call returns a `Completable`
- The `Single` never logically throws an error, since it either fetches an empty or a non-empty `readings` list
- When the entire Rx call chain is terminated, perform the `jobFinished()` callback
- On the success of the entire Rx call chain, delete those `reading`s from the `Dao`
- On success of the `Single`, but error of the `Completable`, update the readings in the `Dao`

My current code is as follows:

```
  Single.create<List<Reading>> {
        readings = readingDao.getNextUploadBatch()

        if (readings.isEmpty()) {
            jobFinished(job, false)
            return@create
        }

        it.onSuccess(readings)
    }
            .flatMapCompletable { api.uploadSensorReadings(it) }
            .doOnTerminate {
                jobFinished(job, !readingDao.isEmpty())
            }
            .subscribeOn(rxSchedulers.network)
            .observeOn(rxSchedulers.database)
            .subscribe(
                    {
                        readingDao.delete(*readings.toTypedArray())
                    },
                    {
                        markCurrentReadingsAsNotUploading()
                    }
            )
```

The logical problem with the above code is (haven't tested it in runtime, but it compiles) that:

- I want to cut off the code starting from the `flatMapCompletable` if `readings` list is empty
- I do not want `doOnTerminate` to execute if `readings` is empty
- I do not want the `onComplete` part (the first `{}` block) of `subscribe` to execute unless `readings` was non-empty, and the `Completable` returned a success as well
- I do not want the `onError` part (the second `{}` block) of `subscribe` to execute unless `readings` was non-empty, and the `Completable` failed

I'm not sure how to implement my workflow as an efficient and neat Rx call chain. Any suggestions would be dearly welcome!

Comment: im not gonna even try to wrap my head on what you're trying to do on a friday night, but as a general (and personal) suggestion I would say you should break these long chains of rx calls into multiple methods or Rx calls. Why? maintenance. Debugging this sucker in 8 months is gonna be a nightmare due to the chain of events. Not to even mention a crash report with just a stacktrace

Comment: It's actually seems to be a pretty straightforward task. I just have a knowledge gap in how to actually implement it in Rx. I've definitely seen much much more complex Rx code; just takes a bit of time to get your head wrapped around it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to perform something different depending on a value, think of `flatMap`:

```
Single.fromCallable(() -> readingDao.getNextUploadBatch())
.subscribeOn(rxSchedulers.network)
.flatMapCompletable(readings -> {
    if (readings.isEmpty()) {
        jobFinished(job, false);
        return Completable.complete();
    }
    return api.uploadSensorReadings(readings)
           .doFinally(() -> jobFinished(job, !readingDao.isEmpty()))
           .observeOn(rxSchedulers.database)
           .doOnComplete(() -> readingDao.delete(readings.toTypedArray()))
})
.subscribe(() -> /* ignored */, error -> markCurrentReadingsAsNotUploading());
```

Comment: That is incredibly similar to what I came up with as well a few hours after posting this question! Did a bit of research and found that returning `Completable.complete()` would be an alternate empty return value to skip the next `Completable`. Thanks!